# custom uitableviewcells in storyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ios5, xcode-storyboard

I think I got all the steps down but I must be missing something because I can't make a connection from the labels in the cell to the code.

Here's what I'm doing:

1. set style of cell to custom
2. dragging some labels onto the prototype cell.
3. adding a new file to the project and making it a subclass of UITableViewCell
4. in the identity inspector of the cell im trying to customize, I set its class to the new class I just created.
5. TRY to control drag from the labels on the cell to the headerfile of the class I just created to setup an IBOutlet, but it won't let me.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Declare the label as a property in the custom cell class. In the table view controller, `alloc` or `dequeue` the cell as your custom type, not as `UITableViewCell`. In the Xcode storyboard, control drag from the cell itself (for example, the far bottom right corner) to the label that is in the cell to connect the outlet.

Comment: Also if that still doesn't work, go onto the cell in the storyboard and where it says Identifier type Cell or whatever your using in you table view controller

Comment: And if THAT doesn't work, use the Connections Inspector from the right-most pane to connect the outlet to the UI widget.  You'll still have to hand-code the IBOutlets in your @interface. Don't know why XCode won't see it and let you control-drag to the code...