# Customizing all table views in app using iOS 5

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, customization

Perhaps I'm searching for the wrong keywords, but I'm surprised there wasn't already a similar question.  If there is, please let me know and I'll delete this question.

What's the best way to customize all table views in an app targeted for iOS 5 or later?

`UIAppearance` has proved to be very useful for customizing all navigation bars, tab bars, and the like throughout an app.  Is there a similar way to customize table view and table view cells?

So far I've been programmatically configuring each table view separately.  This might not be the best idea as I plan to have different themes the user can select.  I've been thinking about creating a separate class that returns the appropriate image for the table view (or cell) based on the theme the user has selected.  Would this be a suitable approach (if there's nowhere to easily customize all the table views)?

Comment: What exactly d you change in appearance? Can you make a rough list?

Answer (score 0):

The most used way to customise table views is through defining table cells in the nib files:
http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/custom-uitableviewcell/
or storyboards:
[custom uitableviewcells in storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8663118/custom-uitableviewcells-in-storyboard)

I haven't do any tweaks by appearance class yet, but it may be helpful. If you want to to this programatically, use the decorator pattern to ease your and further user's life in joining produced code into the project:
http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/decorator

I hope this is helpful

Comment: If I customize the table views through nib files, I'll need to have a nib file for each "theme" the table view has, right?

Comment: Yes, which is good in sense of further maintain and modification of themes in case when quick changes will be needed. As long as you keep your nib files in order this will only help you finding appropriate style quicker and modify it in visual editor, which is really fast.

Comment: You can also try to do it with User Defined Runtime Attributes which comes along with nib files and storyboard. They work since iOS 5.0 you can use them as stated here: http://www.wannabegeek.com/?p=395